# Samsung Galaxy Note 4 is stuck in a boot loop

Tags: cyanogenmod, factory-reset, boot-loop, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-4

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 SM-N910G. I have absolutely no idea why it's stuck in a boot loop, and I can't even go to recovery mode by holding Vol Up + Home + Power.

It was constantly restarting even when it showed a blue warning that it is going to boot on recovery mode.

Then I flashed it with ODIN using a tar I downloaded. I'm a novice, so I just followed a guide on the internet. Now it says set warranty bit recovery? and still doesn't start on recovery mode or otherwise.

Holding VOL Down + Home + Power always takes me to the download mode without an issue, and also the phone vibrates twice every time it reboots.

Any help to recover the phone would be greatly appreciated. I wouldn't mind installing something like CyanogenMod if that's an option, or somehow factory reset the thing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already 5 months old, but for future reference

**1.** It sounds like you already have ODIN so I won't bother linking that, but just double check you have the latest version [here](http://odindownload.com/)

**2.** You will need your stock firmware so you can find that [here](https://samsung-firmware.org/model/SM-N910G/). Just make sure you download the proper firmware for your region.

- If you get one file, it will have everything inside it: AP + CP + CSC.
- If you get multiple files, there will be separate files for AP, CP & CSC.

**3.**  Once you have both of those downloaded onto your computer, boot your device in download mode. Most of the time you can do this by holding the volume down button on startup and then pressing the volume up button to enter download mode.

**4.** Open Odin on your computer and load the firmware you downloaded into the AP slot

**5.** Connect your phone while it in download mode and wait for it to show up in ODIN

**6.** Press the start button and wait for it to say PASS.

**7.** Reboot and wait, this first boot will take some time.

You can also check out this tutorial with pictures [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-s/499009-guide-samsung-how-flash-stock-rom-via-odin-new-interface.html)